# Lubuntu 14.x - no create link or shortcut menu on right click

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, shortcuts, lxde, symbolic-link

I have to use good old

```
ln -s
```

command to create a desktop short cut. I am on Lubuntu  14.x running LXDE 
There is no right click menu on the folder tree that means : right click --> create desktop short cut OR on the desktop menu . Right click --> new --> shortcut.
How do I add this functionality

Comment: see if arronax works on lubuntu

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Linux, where to make coffee, you first have to take a pottery class to craft your cup, somehow make a fire, and blacksmith the spoon. You do have the beans, the clay and the metal though.